# How to stop encrypting medium in Virtualbox?

Tags: virtualbox, encryption

I accidently run encrypting medium in Virtubox and it tooks extremely slowly. I assume it will run a few hours.

Is it possible to stop this process (and possibly roll back) without damage the data on the medium?

[image: encrypting medium in virtualbox]

There is no **STOP** button.

*(I use Win 10 and Virtualbox v5.0)*

Comment: I can guarantee you that if you, close that window, you will cause file corruption.  So it is not possible to stop the process.

Comment: How critical is the VDI file? Do you have a backup of it?